dd-wrt access cutoff
I'm managing a few dd-wrt routers.  I have one running on a Netgear NightHawk AC2600 (r7450), which we'll call router007.  This router is successfully routing packets among wired and wireless segments.  For the last couple of hours when I try to connect to router007:

via Firefox: Secure Connection Failed, PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR.  This suggests that cipher negotiation failed, but I'm fairly certain this is not what happened due to the lack of recent enough updates or configuration changes at the router and at the client machine.

via Chromium: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.  Checking the site date (circled "i" to the left of the URL): "Your connection to this site is not secure."

via ssh:
  > ssh root@router007
  kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
  Connection reset by [router007's IP address] port 22

  > ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no root@router007
  kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
  Connection reset by [router007's IP address] port 22


via telnet (to https ports, should be 8080)
  > telnet router007 8080
  Trying [router007's IP address]...
  Connected to router007.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  Connection closed by foreign host.

  > telnet router007 443
  Trying [router007's IP address]...
  Connected to router007.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  Connection closed by foreign host.



It's running "DD-WRT v3.0-r54248 std (11/29/23)", so I haven't flashed anything recently.  It's configuration is unchanged since May and I successfully accessed the web GUI about two weeks ago.
The client from which I am working is running "Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64".  Apt was last updated on 22 June, but the last upgrade (or dist-upgrade) was 06 June.  "ssh -v root@router007" reports "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1".
The only other "obvious" configuration difference currently is that local DNS is down, so I'm resolving router007's address via /etc/hosts.  (And I think I've checked about fifty times that the address there is correct and I have neither typo'ed in an incorrect router007 on another line nor typo'ed "router007" on its line.  Make that fifty-one times.)  However, our other dd-wrt routers are perfectly accessible currently, so this would have to be a weird interaction to affect only the one.
Remediation tried:

Reboot the router.  No change.
Wait 10 minutes and attempt to access again.  No change.  (I don't think we ever set a maximum number of wrong attempts to trigger a timeout.)

So I don't seem to have any access mode to modify this router...  Any idea what to fix to regain access.  (Like everyone else using dd-wrt, I'd really rather avoid having to reset and reconfigure from scratch.)
